# Reasons for Task Manager crashes in windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, crash, windows-8.1, task-manager

*There could be a number of reasons for Task Manager crashing. I believe I am doing the right thing in making this a community wiki. Here is my original post before I found the cause.*

My task manager crashes in Windows 8.1. I open it using the right click on the start menu or using the keyboard shortcut.

It will crash immediately or when I show more details and try to interact with the view menu for "always on top" and "minimize to tray". The program just disappears and only by looking into the event viewer do I see there are crash events.

This is a new install (1 week old) and do not know when it occurred. It seemed to occur when I 
enabled UAC.

```
I have tried finding any drivers that need updating.  
I have tried disabling any running programs.
I have tried the SFC scan now command to check integrity.  
System restore date lists approximately when i first installed windows.
```

Here are the event viewer logs.
**First, the information event telling me there is a crash log.**

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
Problem signature:
P1: Taskmgr.exe
P2: 6.3.9600.16384
P3: 5215d00b
P4: Taskmgr.exe
P5: 6.3.9600.16384
P6: 5215d00b
P7: c0000005
P8: 0000000000043882
P9: 
P10: 
Attached files:
These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_Taskmgr.exe_(someguid)
Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: dd180f3e-4b86-11e3-8277-002522ea094d
Report Status: 4100
Hashed bucket:
```

**The error event**

```
Faulting application name: Taskmgr.exe, version: 6.3.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215d00b
Faulting module name: Taskmgr.exe, version: 6.3.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215d00b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000043882
Faulting process id: 0x7a4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cedf93cc33dd88
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Taskmgr.exe
Report Id: 09e2cbbc-4b87-11e3-8277-002522ea094d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Can my post be made in to a community wiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RAMDisk**

My crash was caused by SoftPerfect RAM Disk. Once I unmounted the RAM disk drive, the crashing of task manager ended. [Here is a forum discusssion.](http://www.softperfect.com/board/read.php?16,14172)

**ProgramData folder**

Another reason I looked at was junctioning the ProgramData folder. In having a solid state drive there are reasons for moving folders to other drives. Saving space and saving the life time of the capacity of the drive. One method is to [junction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a folder to another drive.

The process involves copying the folder to another drive, creating a junction pointing from the original location to the new location.

Problem sets in when copying (mostly via robocopy) and the permissions are not also transferred. Since some of the folders the people transfer are windows operated folders, you sometimes need to use safe mode command prompt to complete the process. Check with a robocopy first and compare permissions. Some reported robocopy still did not copy permissions even when instructed to.

**Update drivers**

Some believe up to date drivers are needed, namely, video drivers.

Comment: I've been experiencing the same crash, and the RAMDisk was also the cause.

Comment: Same here, experienced crashes and RAMDisk was the cause. Unmount the drive, and close ramdisk and the crashes went away.